# pandas convert all float columns into int

Tags: pandas

There are several float columns, I want to convert all of float columns into int.

prior to knowing the column names of those float columns, How do I convert all of them into int type in one line?

Comment: do you want `df.round().astype('Int64')` ? you can also look at `df.select_dtypes()` to include only numerical columns , just guessing, otherwise Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Comment: Hi, @anky_91 could you write an answer with the `select_dtypes`? thanks

Comment: I dont have a test dataset , but you can try `m = df.select_dtypes(np.number)` , `df[m.columns]= m.round().astype('Int64')` ? you can read about `Int64` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) which handles NaN values too..

Comment: just test, it 's working. Thanks, you can write down an answer, I'll accept

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) first and `round` them and finally convert to `Int64` using `df.astype` which supports Nullable Int dtype:

```
m = df.select_dtypes(np.number)
df[m.columns]= m.round().astype('Int64')
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a simple for loop for this:

```
# say df is the dataframe
for c in df.columns:
    if df[c].dtype == np.float:
        df[c] = df[c].astype(int)
```

Comment: It will give an error if that column contains null values, I have used Int64 instead of int and write into CSV but when I am reading the same CSV, it shows float. How to solve this problem

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Answers the question.